# How to use current date in News API url Query

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a script that I run daily that query News API for specific topics.  Every time I run the script, I have to change the date manually.  Is there a way for the date of the query to be the date I actually run it.

Below is the code that I'm working with, but I can't seem to find the right way to do this

```
import datetime


keywords = ["bitcoin", "ethereum"]
date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=' + ' OR '.join(keywords)) + '&language=en' + '&from=(date)' + '&apiKey='
```

I would like for the &from=(today's date) instead of manually changing it every time I run it.